# Adaptive server anywhere ASA SqlAnywhere 8.0 ODBC driver

Tags: odbc, sybase, sqlanywhere

Well, I've searched the interwebs like crazy and I am unable to find this driver.

I am trying to convert data from a client's database that was built using the ASA 8.0 engine.  ASA 8 has been out of support since 2008. The software company that created this no longer supports it, so can't provide me with the drivers.  I've scoured the web and can't find anything.

I managed to get the installation files for this old software called BailCredit built by a company called SentryLink.  I found what I presume to be the ODBC driver in the installation files (dbodbc8.dll) and I've tried manually registering that (Windows Server 2008 R2) but didn't get anywhere.  When I try to create a new datasource, the ODBC Data Source Administrator gives me an error.

My company has done hundreds of data migrations and this is the first time I've had to resort to this.

I'd post a link to the database file, but simply can't because of privacy.

Please help if you can!  Thanks in Advance.

Matt

Comment: You may have to upgrade the database, then use the current SQLAnywhere ODBC drivers.

Comment: I did try to do the upgrade, but you must be connected to the database in order to perform an upgrade and the newer version of SQL Anywhere wouldn't allow connection.

Comment: So, after struggling with this for quite some time, I tried the install on 32-bit version of Windows Server 2003 and this was successful.  This question can be withdrawn.

Comment: Actually, you can submit that as the answer, then accept it.

Comment: I am facing exactly this same problem right now, could you please post how you did this? thanks.

Comment: @CarlosAlloatti: I wasn't able to find this commercially available anywhere.  I happened to be able to get my hands on the installation for the software package that was using SQLAnywhere 8.  By installing this, it installed the necessary drivers (but only worked on 32-bit OS).  I wish I had a better answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I wasn't able to find this commercially available anywhere. I happened to be able to get my hands on the installation for the software package that was using SQLAnywhere 8. By installing this, it installed the necessary drivers (but only worked on 32-bit OS).

Answer (score 2):

For 64 Bit operating system you need to copy the dll's to %windir%\syswow64\ so you need to change install.cmd to the following code. The rest is the same.

```
COPY %~dp0dbcon8.dll  %windir%\syswow64\dbcon8.dll
COPY %~dp0dblgen8.dll %windir%\syswow64\dblgen8.dll
COPY %~dp0dbodbc8.dll %windir%\syswow64\dbodbc8.dll

regedit %~dp0SAS8.REG

pause
```

It take's me a few hours to figure it out i hope it help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I finally solved it.

OPTION 1:

Get a copy of the following files from a computer with a working setup of the SQL Anywhere ODBC driver:

```
dbodbc8.dll
dbcon8.dll
dblgen8.dll
```

Create an install.cmd file with this:

```
COPY %~dp0dbcon8.dll  %SystemRoot%\system32\dbcon8.dll
COPY %~dp0dblgen8.dll %SystemRoot%\system32\dblgen8.dll
COPY %~dp0dbodbc8.dll %SystemRoot%\system32\dbodbc8.dll

regedit %~dp0SAS8.REG

pause
```

Create an SAS8.REG file with this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\Adaptive Server Anywhere 8.0]
"Driver"=hex(2):25,00,57,00,49,00,4e,00,44,00,49,00,52,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,\
  00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,64,00,62,00,6f,00,64,00,62,00,\
  63,00,38,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00
"Setup"=hex(2):25,00,57,00,49,00,4e,00,44,00,49,00,52,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,\
  00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,64,00,62,00,6f,00,64,00,62,00,\
  63,00,38,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers]
"Adaptive Server Anywhere 8.0"="Installed"
```

Run install.cmd

This will work when Windows is installed in C:\WINDOWS, otherwise edit the registry entries.

OPTION 2:

If someone left a copy of the Powerbuilder CD in the client's computer, look for the folder asa801runtime and install that to get the ODBC driver working

EDIT:

Example connection string with default username/password:

```
Driver={Adaptive Server Anywhere 8.0};UID=dba;PWD=sql;DatabaseName=base;EngineName=gestion;CommLinks=TCPIP(HOST=GRA06:2638)
```